# NSTextView not visible

Tags: cocoa

I want to create a Bordered Rectangle with a Text/Label positioned in the top-left with AppKit that looks like:

[image]

The text view should have the same border and background color as the rectangle's border, and a padding around the actual text, not a fixed width/height constant.

I rewrote the above view in AppKit with NSTextView, but I can't see the textview, just the border:

[image]

```
class JumperView: NSView {
    let label: String
    
    private let borderWidth: CGFloat = 4
    private let borderColor = NSColor(red: 250 / 255, green: 255 / 255, blue: 0 / 255, alpha: 1).cgColor
    private let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 8
    
    private var labelView: NSTextView!
    
    required init(frame: NSRect, label: String) {
        self.label = label
        super.init(frame: frame)

        wantsLayer = true
        layer!.borderWidth = borderWidth
        layer!.borderColor = borderColor
        layer!.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        
        setupLabelView()
        
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.labelView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            self.labelView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor),
            self.labelView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor),
        ])
    }
    
    private func setupLabelView() {
        labelView = NSTextView()
        labelView.string = label
        labelView.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 24, weight: .bold)
//        labelView.textContainerInset = .init(width: 8, height: 4)
        labelView.wantsLayer = true
        labelView.layer!.borderWidth = borderWidth
        labelView.layer!.borderColor = borderColor
        labelView.layer!.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        labelView.layer!.backgroundColor = borderColor
        labelView.backgroundColor = NSColor(cgColor: borderColor)!
        addSubview(labelView)
    }
    
    override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        fatalError()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError()
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why the text view isn't showing up. Would appreciate the help!

Comment: Tip: `NSTextField` is much easier to use as label.

Comment: @Willeke that's what I thought and had used previously. However, inset is not supported out of the box unlike `NSTextView`. Will share what I come up with!